# Unit testing of functions

Tags: php, unit-testing, phpunit

I have got a PHP file in which there are some functions (not included in a class). I am using PHPUnit to testing. When I try to generate in a simply way a test file from a file containing functions, the log says:

```
Could not find class...
```

Is there any possibility to test functions which are not methods?

Comment: Edit your qeustion. I will take -1 from it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, you can with something like this:

### includes/functions.php

```
function my_function() {
    return true;
}
```

### tests/MyFunctionTest.php

```
require_once '../includes/functions.php';

class MyFunctionTest extends PHPUnit_Framework_TestCase
{
    public function testReturnValue()
    {
        $return_value = my_function();
        $this->assertTrue($return_value);
    }
}
```

So as long as your function is within scope you can call it from your test method just like any other PHP function in any other PHP framework or project.

Comment: Thanks, Treffynnon. Your solution is excellent for me :) I'll do this as you proposed.

Comment: Yes, well like this is better then making method out of the function for testing purpose. :)

Comment: Why has this been downvoted? Perhaps the downvoter could fill us all in on their greater wisdoms in this area?

Comment: LOL! Even procedural programming is object oriented. What you hate is non-useage of object oriented language constructs. If I remember correctly object oriented was originally written in C as a library that became C++.

Answer (score 0):

If I'm right then PhpUnit works only with classes hence methods. So just convert them into the methods for testing purpose. Shouldn't be hard.

Comment: I just don't want to create another file containing the same. But you're right: it's easy :)